# Normalize the PlotLegends and z values for two DensityPlot

Tags: color, legending

I'm trying to compare two `DensityPlot`s:

```
Module[{R1, R2, x, Δ},
 R1 = 15;
 R2 = 5;

 Row @ {
   DensityPlot[-((R1 + R2 + R1 x - R2 x - R2 Δ - R1 x Δ + R2 x Δ)/(-2 + Δ)),
    {x, 0, 1}, {Δ, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 700, FrameLabel -> {"% talented", "delta"}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic],
   DensityPlot[-((
     2 R2 + R1 x - R2 x - R2 Δ - R1 x Δ + R2 x Δ)/(-2 + Δ)),
     {x, 0, 1}, {Δ, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 700, FrameLabel -> {"% talented", "delta"}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic]
   }]
```

but it would be easier if the colors were coding for the same values in the two graphs. I was able to set the same range of values for the legend with:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 15}}], Right]
```

but how do I change the command so that the colors of my graphs will represent the whole range of values from 0 to 15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be to set the scaling of the colors yourself: (I slightly cleaned up the code a bit, so that we do not get confused by double-setting the options)

```
Module[{R1, R2, x, \[CapitalDelta], eqs},
 R1 = 15;
 R2 = 5;
 eqs = {-((R1 + R2 + R1 x - R2 x - R2 \[CapitalDelta] - 
        R1 x \[CapitalDelta] + 
        R2 x \[CapitalDelta])/(-2 + \[CapitalDelta])), -((2 R2 + 
        R1 x - R2 x - R2 \[CapitalDelta] - R1 x \[CapitalDelta] + 
        R2 x \[CapitalDelta])/(-2 + \[CapitalDelta]))};
 Row[DensityPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, {\[CapitalDelta], 0, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Medium, FrameLabel -> {"% talented", "delta"}, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 15}}], Right], 
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][#/15] &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ eqs
  ]]
```

I use `ColorFunctionScaling->False` to keep Mathematica from rescaling the colors. Note that I hardcoded the `15`. You might want to adjust that.

Note: I kept your version of the legend.

**EDIT, including `ContourPlot`**

For `ContourPlot`, we have to define the legend differently (I **guess** this is due to the fact that Mathematica tries to build the legend around the existing contours of the graph, thus cuts off the rest of the legend - hence we apply some force)

```
 Module[{R1, R2, x, \[CapitalDelta], eqs, cf},
 R1 = 15;
 R2 = 5;
 cf = ColorData["SunsetColors"][#/15] &;
 eqs = {-((R1 + R2 + R1 x - R2 x - R2 \[CapitalDelta] - 
        R1 x \[CapitalDelta] + 
        R2 x \[CapitalDelta])/(-2 + \[CapitalDelta])), -((2 R2 + 
        R1 x - R2 x - R2 \[CapitalDelta] - R1 x \[CapitalDelta] + 
        R2 x \[CapitalDelta])/(-2 + \[CapitalDelta]))};
 Row[
  ContourPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, 
  {\[CapitalDelta], 0, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  FrameLabel -> {"% talented", "delta"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{cf, {0, 15}}, 30], Right],
  ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ eqs]]
```

There is probably a more direct way to implement that. The way I suggest here specifies the `ColorFunction` once more with the proper scaling and creates the legend based on that.

Note: this legend works for both `DensityPlot` and `ContourPlot`, it seems.

**end of edit**

The resulting image (`DensityPlot`) looks like (I like `SunsetColors`):

[image]

Comment: that's great. Any idea why the legend is messed up when I use ContourPlot instead of DensityPlot?

Comment: glad you like it - I added an edit to fix things for `ContourPlot`. I hope this works for you!